# Remove unwanted tags with XSL

Tags: html, xslt, tags

I've got some unknown content coming in as a description, maybe something like this:

```
<description>
  <p>
    <span>
      <font>Hello</font>
    </span>
    World! 
    <a href="/index">Home</a>
  </p>
</description>
```

There could conceivable be any HTML tag. I don't want all the tags. The tags I want to allow are p, i, em, strong, b, ol, ul, li and a. So, for example, <font> would be stripped, but <p> and <a> would remain. I'm assuming I have to match the ones I want (and make sure there's nothing to match the others), but can't work out how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Whitelist** those elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::description or self::p or self::i or 
                               self::em or self::strong or self::b or 
                               self::ol or self::ul or self::li or self::a)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this removes the undesired elements *and* anything below them. To just strip the `font` element itself, for example, but allow its children, modify the last template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::description or self::p or self::i or 
                           self::em or self::strong or self::b or 
                           self::ol or self::ul or self::li or self::a)]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

An equivalent (and slightly cleaner) solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-3">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="description|p|i|em|strong|b|ol|ul|li|a">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The opposite approach is to **blacklist** the unwanted elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="font|span"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Again, add an `apply-templates` to the final template if you want to allow children of the skipped elements.

Comment: +1 good answer. You can simplify the whitelisting a lot tho... Change your identity template's match attribute to `"description | p | i | ..."`. Then change the empty template's match attribute to `"*"`, with `priority="-3"` just to make sure it takes a back seat.

Comment: @LarsH - I was just updating to show that as an alternative :) Not sure why I didn't originally do it that way.

Comment: @LarsH - Ended up being slightly different than suggested, because it's actually the Identity template that should take a back seat.

Comment: @LarsH - ...assuming you still want to match other node types with `node()`. Otherwise you'll still end up with ambiguous matches or accidentally allow everything.

Comment: You're right that we still need an identity template to copy text, comments, attributes, and such -- I'd forgotten that. But that template doesn't need `apply-templates` inside, because only elements can have children. As you say, the identity template needs to be lower priority than the match="*", which needs to be lower priority than the match="description|etc.".

Comment: @LarsH - Right, you are. Additionally, the root node will be handled by the built-in template, so I'll go ahead and make that one a little cleaner.